# How to extract text from xpath and store into a list for further iteration

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have following code and not getting clue how to extract the days from the xpath and store into some lists with some indexes

Basically the xpath identifies only date but on my web page it contain both Date and Days and Days are not part of xpath.

```
dar = time.localtime(time.time())
das = time.localtime(time.time()- 86400)
dat = time.localtime(time.time() - (86400 * 2))
dau = time.localtime(time.time() - (86400 * 3))
dav = time.localtime(time.time() - (86400 * 4))
date = {"Date0": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dar), "Date1": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",das), "Date2": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dat), "Date3": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dau),"Date4": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dav)}

for i in range(4):
        dayss = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='"+date["Date"+str(i)]+"']").text
        lists = dayss.split()
        print(lists[0])
        print("######")
        print(lists[1])
```

I'm getting below output to make you understand whats on lists[0] and lists[1]

```
06-Sep
######
Fri
05-Sep
######
Thu
04-Sep
######
Wed
03-Sep
######
Tue
```

### Expected Output

```
['Fri','Thu','Wed','Tue']
```

So that based on the above output I should able to access each index such as `lists[0]` must return `'Fri'` and `lists[1]` must return `'Thu'` and so on. But currently with `lists[1]` it's returning all the days and not able to pass the iterator `lists[i]` always getting `index out of range`

Following is the below html:

```
<td class="selected_date" id="2019-09-02" width="68" align="center">02-Sep<br>Mon</td>
```

Comment: you need to share HTML code(html having your above data), so the people here can see the structure of your HTML and help you with the Xpath

Comment: @Subham Jain: I have updated my question with html code

Comment: updated code ....

Comment: @Chinmoy This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Split the text with newline and append it to empty list.

```
dar = time.localtime(time.time())
das = time.localtime(time.time()- 86400)
dat = time.localtime(time.time() - (86400 * 2))
dau = time.localtime(time.time() - (86400 * 3))
dav = time.localtime(time.time() - (86400 * 4))
date = {"Date0": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dar), "Date1": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",das), "Date2": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dat), "Date3": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dau),"Date4": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dav)}

daylist=[]
for i in range(4):
        dayss = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='"+date["Date"+str(i)]+"']").text
        lists = dayss.split("\n")
        daylist.append(lists[1])

print(daylist)
```

**Output:**

```
['Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Tue']
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for

Comment: @Chinmoy : Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath seems fine as your html tag have both value and so your are getting both values.

You need to declare one more list let say list2 and add only list[1] in each iteration for list2. Thats how at the end your list2 will contain only data index which you need

**OR**

You can use index in split function itself

In java it is like

```
tim.split(":")[0];
```

In python I guess it is like

```
tim.split(':', 1)
```